# Add an Android app user to beta testing list on Google play store

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

I have an Android app on Google play store with alpha and beta testers (in addition to production) and so far everything was working well.
I am trying to add a new user to the closed beta testing list on google play store. This user is already using the app on production.
For some reason, although his email address is in the beta testing list, he cannot see and download the version that is published to beta. (Only the version on production).
Any reason for that or a way to fix this?

Edit:
I continue to experience this problem: Once a user have already downloaded the app on production, he cannot become a beta tester. Does that make sense?

Comment: As far i know you can only see app on PlayStore which is in beta or alpha if you have the tester privileges and if you have valid link to download the app. If i am wrong, please someone correct me.

Comment: please double check everything again!, you must add his google account to the testing list and save updates (this could take up to 2 hours). and he must be logged In GP using the added account to be able to see the app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with a Google Play representative, I have finally solved the mystery:

First, a user must uninstall the production app and only then he will be able to see and download the alpha/beta version through the Play Store. (He must also follow the invitation link of course).

Second, surprisingly, when you promote a version from alpha to beta - alpha testers can no longer download this version. More precisely, according to the representative -

"When you promote to beta the testers need to opt-out of the alpha test using the same opt-in link, then uninstall the app from their device, and wait 24 hours"

This in some of the cases was my problem since I assumed alpha testers can still have access to the new app version after it is promoted to beta.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to have both production and beta versions.

1. You need a fresh beta release, which means its build code should be **higher** than your production release.
2. You need to invite/add the beta testers, ask them to follow the link to take part in the testing etc.
3. The beta testers need to wait few hours for the beta release to roll up. Probably also have to remove the production version.